# Node.js client socket not getting destroyed from node.js server

Tags: node.js, tcpclient, destroy, tcpserver

Everytime a socket gets an error, closes or ends I call this function:

```
destroySocket = function(){   
    socket.destroy();
    console.log("Socket gone");
    destroySocket = function(){};
    delete this;
}
```

And that function is getting called here:

```
socket.on('error', function(had_error){ console.log(had_error); destroySocket(); });
socket.on('close', function(){ destroySocket(); });
socket.on('end', function () { destroySocket(); });
```

When the user disconnects, I do get "Socket gone", but after this happens I start receiving this error:

```
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
```

Why Am I getting this? This has never happened to me before, it's supposed to be destroyed when `socket.destroy();` is getting called

Comment: Why are you trying to destroy it? The socket is already being closed due to error ...

Comment: @mscdex Is not getting destroyed for some reason, I keep getting the "This socket has been ended by the..." error every random time.

Comment: Plus the `socket.destroy();` is only getting called once.